# Tracking a loop in JavaScript doesn't seem to work?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, textfield

This is just a summary of a a bigger piece of code. I'm trying to track a JavaScript loop by displaying the index in a "text" element. Yet, however long the loop is, I still see **only** the final "End" message:

```js
 sform.smsg.value = "Begin";
 for (let i=0; i<1000000; i++) sform.smsg.value = i;
 sform.smsg.value = "End";
```

```html
<form name="sform">
  <input type="text" id="smsg" name="smsg" disabled>
</form>
```

Comment: The code runs so fast that you are only going to see the last value.

Comment: The code **blocks** while it runs, so whatever you do in that loop, if it changes the page, you'll see only the last step (unless it's asynchronous)

Comment: @imvain2 That’s not the correct reason.

Comment: But **how** can I still track the index advancement, at least to some extent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is **synchronous** so it **blocks** while it runs. Whatever you do in that loop, if it changes the page, you'll see only the last step (unless it's asynchronous).